# Possibility of updating Apple Indoor Maps at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

In WWDC2019 Apple announces the [Indoor Maps Program](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/245/). For our business application we are looking for a solution to build interactive and updatable private indoor maps. Since we are working with Apple devices this new feature looks promising. 
While I was reading through their documentation, I found nothing about **updating maps at runtime**.
We want to connect our app with websocket and update the map when a specific event occurs.
For example in our factory are different machines. 
When one machine gets an error, we would like to mark this machine red, send push notification to an operator and guide him to this machine with indoor positioning system. And so on...
Has someone experience with a similar use case in the Indoor Maps Program and know if this is possible?

Comment: It sounds like you would augment the map at runtime with map annotations. The machines wouldn't be part of the base map, but rather annotations added to the map. You could then control the appearance of the annotation.

Comment: For now this sounds like the solution for me. Rather than annotations I would prefer custom anchored map overlays to handle zoom in and out. When using annotations for machines, which are very close together, I guess it becomes confusing very fast. If I am right disabling annotations to not zoom together with the map, isn't possible?!

Comment: You can use annotation clustering to show a composite annotation as you zoom out